# 2 composable on each other, shows background corners. Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to implement swiping effect in Jetpack Compose, so I need to put 2 composable of same size but different color on each other.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(12.dp).height(100.dp).clip(CircleShape).background(Color.Black)) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(100.dp).clip(CircleShape).background(
                Color.White)){

            }
        }
```

Here, background composable's corners are shown?

What to do? Help, Please.

Change corners values.

[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cISXy.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my case, I needed to implement swipe like in chats, so I needed to put 2 composables on each other. To solve the problem with corners, I made the color of composable that is behind Color.Transparent when it is not moved, when it is moved I just transform the color to another one. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works for you but using a Box @Composable make's it easier to stack components on top of each other

Example:

```
Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(12.dp)
        .height(100.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .background(
            Color.Black
        )) {
    }
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .background(
            Color.White
        )){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see black pixels on the edges is the smoothing. Pixels on the edges are semi-transparent so you can see underlying view.

You can try to not draw the underlying background while the view is not swiped. Something like this:

```kotlin
if (swiping) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(12.dp)
            .height(100.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) { ... }
}

Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .background(Color.White)
) { ... }
```

Comment: Not right answer

Comment: @IlhomSoliev can you explain what's wrong? Did you find the right solution?

Comment: Yes, I posted the solution. Hope it helps.